# Sending JSON data to WordPress backend with Ajax need decoding twice

Tags: json, ajax, wordpress, http-post

I have a large CSV file that I decided to divide into chunks and send to the server One after the other is saved to the database but when I send the JSON data to the WordPress backend it needs decoding twice, It's working but is this the right solution? What should I do the parse it one time?

Here is the Ajax Code:

```
parser.pause();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: papa_parse.ajaxUrl,
    data: {
        action: "handleCsvImport",
        currentChunk: currentChunk, 
        depth : arrayDepth(results.data),
        parsedData : JSON.stringify(results.data)
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log("started 1", data);
        parser.resume();
    }
    
});
```

The prasedData is the JSON data it sending and here it looks like:

[image]

Here are the results: **I was expecting the first print_r to work it didn't**

[image]

Comment: If you set the content type correctly in your Ajax request, you don't need to manually decode it again. Add `contentType: 'application/json' ` in the AJAX request.